# Styling Pseudo element ::after shows no line-wrap

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-element

I wanted to create an underline effect for the Headings for my blog using css. For that, I used the Pseudo element `::after` for styling and was able to achieve the following results

[image]

The problem arises when the length of the Headings exceed the single line length, it doesn't follow the wrap-around effect like the one shown below.

[image]

The css style I used to generate this effect is

```css
// styles.sass
h1::after, 
h2::after
  position: absolute
  margin-top: -0.45em
  margin-left: -10px
  display: block
  width: 107%
  height: 0.5em
  background: #EFF239  
  content: ''
  z-index: -1
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd

h2::after
  background: #a5f1b1
```

Could someone guide me, how I could also style the ::after element such that the underline follows the Heading text ?

Comment: You'll have to take a different approach from ::after if you want line wrapping. after is a single pseudo element that doesn't follow the text wrapping in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use pseudo element, rely on box-shadow:

```css
span {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 -.4em 0 #EFF239 inset;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<span>Some text here <br> and here</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue with my problem is that I am using this in a blog theme I created which uses NetlifyCMS (now Decap CMS), and I wanted to change the base stylings of h1, h2 ... 

So, I cannot use your solution directly, but it gave me another idea how to approach it.

Thanks :)